# Caracteres especiales PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5

Buenas, hoy vengo con un pequeño problema que es este

```
echo $consulta;
```

a lo que me responde con:

```
SELECT SUM(carrito_cant) as cantidad FROM carrito_tb WHERE carrito_folio='3041M�Ra' and carrito_NP='NA';
```

devido al caracter ó que lo intercambia por � ya intente con

```
$consulta = utf8_encode ( $consulta );
```

tambien con estos dos:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

pero sin duda ninguno me arroja

```
SELECT SUM(carrito_cant) as cantidad FROM carrito_tb WHERE carrito_folio='3041MóRa' and carrito_NP='NA';
```

Comment: Revisa que tu página web soporta UTF8 vía header y que tu archivo php también está en formato UTF8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sería bueno que pudieras incorporar tu forma de conectarte ya que si utilizas **PDO** tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
$pdo = new Conexion();
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); // <--utf8
```

En caso que que lo hagas a la antigua sería de esta forma:

```
$conexion = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword);
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client ='utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conexion);
mysql_select_db($db,$conexion);
```

con *mysqli* sería

```
<?PHP

@ $db = new mysqli(localhost, "root", "", "biblioteca");

if ($db->connect_error)
    die('Error de Conexion ('.$db->connect_errno.')'.$db->connect_error);

echo "Conexion correcta con la base de datos...".$db->host_info;
echo "Utilizando un charset, por defecto, de tipo: ".$db->character_set_name()";
$db->set_charset('utf8');

echo "Utilizando un nuevo charset de tipo: ".$db->character_set_name();
$db->close();

?>
```

Y por supuesto revisar si la base de datos fue creada con *character = utf8* y la *collation = utf8_general_ci* al igual que la tabla específica a la que consultas.

Comment: De hecho la base de datos si esta en _utf8_general_ci_ y la conexión a la base de datos la hago de esta manera:
`$connectMySql = new mysqli($hostname_connectMySql, $username_connectMySql, $password_connectMySql, $database_connectMySql);` @EduardoMunizaga

Comment: Ok, puse un ejemplo con mysqli a ver si te sirve. Aquí hay otro ejemplo: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_set_charset.asp

Answer (score 2):

Varias opciones para este problema, al parecer intentaste

a)  con el método `utf8_encode()`

b) Agregar el header con el charset para `utf-8` :

```
<?php header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Te recomiendo como tercera opción, guardes tu archivo `php` con codificación `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Mi problema se resolvió usando éste comando al momento de hacer conexión a la base de datos:

```
$connect = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",
    $user,
    $pass,
    array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
```